# When exactly the event $destroy fires in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, destroy

Can you give me the smallest example of an app that will fire the $destroy event?
Does the scope get destroyed when it is not visible anymore? (Ex: ***ng-if*** gets **false**)

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No problem. Just trying to get a better grip of this event that is used in a proyect I am working on.